# stuck running a while loop (beginner)

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

the issue that I have: the loops forever (basic beginner mistake) and the output doesn't change, if I enter the same phrase twice. The code seem to have no issues, but once started, it runs until the memory ends.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izuM3.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should know that `:=` is the "walrus" operator and assigns a value to a variable and then returns it. So something like `if command := 'start'` is assigning the value `'start'` to the variable `command`, and then checking if `'start'` is a truthy value (which it is). What you probably meant to do is `if command == 'start'`

Also, if you want to ask the user for input until they issue the 'quit' command, you'll need to place the `input()` call inside the while loop